# Unit Testing Firestore in Xcode is Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore

Every time I run a test I get this error:

> *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Failed to open DB: Internal: Failed to open LevelDB database*

The following is my code:

```
import XCTest
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
  
  override class func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
  }
  
  func testFetchUsers() {
    Firestore
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        // code...
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You may find interesting: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5423